# datagridview doesn't show list<t> data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

I know that the question asked servel times,
but still it doesn't work.

My code is like that:

```
puclic class student 
{
  private string name;
  private int id;

 get() 
 set()
}


public class form1
{
   List<student> students = new List<studnet>(); 

   student s1 = new student("David", 1);
   student s2 = new student("Josef", 2);

   students.add (s1);
   students.add (s2);

   dataGridView1.DataSource = students;
}
```

After i run it-
The gridview show nothing.

Also the columns name isn't show.

Comment: Change the fields to properties. Magic will happen.

Comment: Change `private string name;` to `public string Name{get; set;};`. Do this for all the fields `id` etc.

Comment: Thanks! This has bitten me in the butt so many times now. I wish .Net would just have fields behave like default properties.. work the needed magic in the background for us.